# Mapbox : MGLSymbolStyleLayer add my custom "iconImage"

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

How can i add custom image for `MGLSymbolStyleLayer`. Below is my code,

```
        let symbolGraphicsLayer = MGLSymbolStyleLayer(identifier: identifier, source: source)

        symbolGraphicsLayer.sourceLayerIdentifier = identifier
        symbolGraphicsLayer.iconImageName = MGLStyleConstantValue<NSString>(rawValue: "assets/myImage")
        symbolGraphicsLayer.iconScale = MGLStyleValue(rawValue: 1)
        symbolGraphicsLayer.isVisible = true
        self.mapView.style?.addLayer(symbolGraphicsLayer)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is your problem that the image doesn't appear? 
You first need to add the image to the style layer, and then you can use it. 
So before that code, you can do:

```
if let image = UIImage(named: "myImage") {
    mapView.style?.setImage(image, forName: "myImage")
}
```

and you can use it afterwards like you said. Just use the name you passed to the setImage method.

I hope this helps other people since the documentation is quite poor for this

Comment: Maybe you know how can you switch between images later after you set a few using this method? (question in details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55144970/switching-on-custom-property-to-change-image-of-mglsymbolstylelayer)